# Stats of elements with a prefix in Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, monitoring

I'm using Redis for several things in my Rails app, each with their own prefix.

1. I run Resque (all of resque's stuff is prefixed with `resque:`
2. We use it as the backing for Rails.cache (I prefix my keys with my app name)
3. We have a couple other gems with built in caching using it (e.g. the geocoder gem prefixes all elements with `geocoder:`)

I'd like to know if there's an easy way to track stats on of the 3 caches running concurrently. e.g. size, hit rate.

I know how to get the stats for the node as a whole using `Rails.cache.stats`, but I'm pretty sure that's reporting Redis stats for everything. Any way to segregate by key prefix?

Answer (score 4):

In Redis, [any lookup based on prefix will be O(n) and is not recommended for regular use in production](http://redis.io/commands/keys). Redis does not do any sort of internal segregation based on prefixes.

As a work-around, you could segregate your three caches into three separate databases and then use [REDIS INFO KEYSPACE](http://redis.io/commands/info) to get stats per database, which in effect would give you stats per cache.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction to hunt in.